# Reduce frequency in which regionDidChangeAnimated is called iphone?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

Is there a way to reduce the number of times in which regionDidChangeAnimated in the MKMapViewDelegate? maybe some property so that I can set a filter on the delta of the changes?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there isn't. Don't you think the documentation would mention it if there were such an option?

Comment: they cant put everything in the documentation because it needs to be as concise as possible, and maybe theres no easy obvious way.

Comment: The documentation contains every public method and property (by definition; if something is not documented, it's not public). A feature that would do what you want would need to be either a property of `MKMapView` or a method in the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol. It exists in neither place.